# A* algorithm that takes account velocity

Tags: java, algorithm, a-star, racing

I'm developing a racing game like http://harmmade.com/vectorracer/ and I have implemented the A* algorithm to use for the AI players. The algorithm is working fine for 1-tile movements, but I don't want the AI players to only move 1 tile at a time (by using only their adjacent points), I need them to be able to accelerate and decelerate when they are closing in on a turn. Their next positions should depend on their previous one, just like Vector Racer.

```
public boolean createRoute() {

    // The list where the points will be added in reverse order (from finish_point)
    ArrayList<Track_Point> path = new ArrayList<>();
    // The list where the unchecked points will be stored
    ArrayList<Track_Point> open = new ArrayList<>();
    // The list where the checked points will be stored
    ArrayList<Track_Point> closed = new ArrayList<>();
    // The starting point is always added as the first point to be checked
    open.add(starting_point);
    Track_Point current;

    while (true) {
        current = null;

        // If all points from the open list have been removed (be being checked), it means that there isn't a possible path from the starting to the finish point
        if (open.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("no route available");
            return false;
        }

        // Selects the point with the lowest F value from the open list
        for (Track_Point temp : open) {
            temp.show();
            if (current == null || temp.getF() < current.getF()) {
                current = temp;
            }
        }

         // If the current point has reached the finish point, break the loop to construct the path
        if (current.equals(finish_point)) {
            break;
        }

        // Removes the current point (with the lowest F value) from the open list
        open.remove(current);
        // Adds the current point (with the lowest F value) to the closed list
        closed.add(current);
        ArrayList<Track_Point> possible_points = createNextPossibleTrackPoints(current);
        //Sets the parent of the possible points
        for (Track_Point tp : possible_points) {
            if (!tp.equals(current)) {
                tp.setParent(current);
            }
        }

        for (Track_Point possible_point : possible_points) {
            double nextG = current.getG() + current.distance(possible_point);
            if (nextG < possible_point.getG()) {
                open.remove(possible_point);
                closed.remove(possible_point);
            }

            if (!open.contains(possible_point) && !closed.contains(possible_point)) {
                possible_point.setParent(current);
                open.add(possible_point);
            }
        }
    }
    //Track_Point current = finish_point;
    while (current.getParent() != null) {
        path.add(current);
        current = current.getParent();
    }
    // optimalRacingLine is the list where all the points will be held in the correct order
    optimalRacingLine.add(starting_point);
    for (int k = path.size() - 1; k >= 0; k--) {
        optimalRacingLine.add(path.get(k));
    }
    return true;
}
```

createPossiblePoints(Point current) so far returns a list of the current point's adjacents.
Each point's H value is calculated in their constructor, as I'm passing the finish point there and it calculates the distance between them.
Each point's G value is calculated when I set a parent to it, the G value is the distance from the new point to their parent + the parent's G value.

How do I modify this code to allow acceleration/deceleration?

The code of Track_Point:

```
package model;

import javafx.geometry.Point2D;

public class Track_Point extends Point2D {

    private Track_Point parent, velocity;
    private double f, g, h;

    public Track_Point(double x, double y) {
    super(x, y);
    }

    public Track_Point(double x, double y, Track_Point f) { // f is the finish point
    super(x, y);
    h = distance(f);
    }

    public void setParent(Track_Point tp) {
    parent = tp;
    g = distance(tp) + tp.getG();
    f = g + h;
    velocity = new Track_Point(getX() - parent.getX(), getY() - parent.getY());
    }

    public Track_Point getParent() {
    return parent;
    }

    public double getG() {
    return g;
    }

    public double getH() {
    return h;
    }

    public double getF() {
    return f;
    }

    public Track_Point getVelocity() {
    return velocity;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
    return "( " + (int) getX() + " , " + (int) getY() + " )";
    }

    public void show() {
    System.out.println(toString());
    }

}
```

Added some screenshots of my failed attempt and the working simple A* version

http://tinypic.com/r/zlakg2/8 - working version

http://tinypic.com/r/2e3u07o/8 - modified version (uses velocity as a parameter in the createNextPossiblePoints method)

Comment: The key point is to represent your x and y velocities as part of the state, in addition to the x and y positions.  Does `Track_Point` contain fields for them?  (You need to show the definition of `Track_Point`.)

Comment: I find a few things confusing (I'm not exactly sure what f, g and h represent, and you seem to be storing the velocity inside a second `Track_Point` object (whose own velocity you ignore?)), but it may be that all you need to do is change `createNextPossibleTrackPoints()` so that instead of generating points adjacent to the current point, they are the actual set of legal positions, i.e. the positions adjacent to where you would go if you added velocity to the current point's location.

Comment: A couple more things (then I have to go I'm sorry): if `distance()` measures the Euclidean distance, then it's not necessarily a lower bound on the remaining number of steps needed to get to the finish, because you could be travelling at more than 1 unit per move -- though I think `distance() / velocity` will be.  Also you might be interested in my own solution to this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6598303/47984.  This computes an exactly optimal (minimum possible number of moves) solution using a breadth-first search of the search space.

Comment: g is the movement cost from the starting to the current point,
h is the estimated distance between the current point and the finish point, f is the summation of the two
the A* algorithm uses a best-first search and to do that, it selects the node with the least cost i.e. the f value
this explanation covers everything up, it's the one i used to implement the A* [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KNXfSOx4eEE)
Track_Point velocity was my failed attempt to solve the issue, I was  passing it as a second parameter in the createPossiblePoints method, and it does create the proper next positions

Comment: the problem is that the AI player only accelerates when it has the chance, resulting in surpassing the target point (if it's behind an obstacle) and only after it surpassed the finish point it starts to decelerate. most of my tracks, while they are valid using the A*, they are considered invalid when I used the modified version.
I will check your solution in a bit, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, don't use an integers for the x/y position. There should be no such thing as '1 tile' in a racing game. Your game world and output can be completely different. For example, consider using doubles to store x and y. Ssh, don't worry, your JFrame doesn't need to know.

## Heuristics

You are using A* to run your AI? Consider these additional heuristics:

- Prefer high velocities; `cost = max velocity - current velocity`
- Stay near inside edge of turn (imagine the turn as the outside edge of a circle); `cost = distance_from(focus of turn)`
- Avoid walls; `cost = isMovable(x, y) ? 0 : infinite/high`
- **EDIT** Prefer shortest path to avoid taking unnecessary moves as your second image does (Breadth First search *not* Djikstra); `cost = steps from first node`

The way A* works is as follows:

1. Use Djikstra (distance from origin) + Greedy (distance to target)
2. Insert your heuristics here
3. Add them all together and choose the lowest number

There's no such thing as f, g, or h; it's just mathematical nonsense you don't need to know.

## Velocity

`velocity = Math.abs(position1 - position2)`; so... `position1 + velocity = position2`. 
You'll need to add the following variables:

- int xVelocity
- int yVelocity

Each moment, `x += xVelocity; y += yVelocity`.
The next position will be `xf = x + xVelocity; yf = y + yVelocity`. Then, you draw a ring around that position as follows:

```
         +yVelocity
            \|/
-xVelocity  -0-  +xVelocity
            /|\
        -yVelocity
```

So the center retains the same velocity, any adjacent side changes one velocity, and any diagonal side changes both velocities.
As for using A* the solution space of a turn is small enough that you can brute force it; don't add `TrackPoint`s to the open list if you bump into a wall and prefer the highest velocity.

Really, that's all there is to it; simple stuff, but it can be tedious and difficult the first few times you need to do it.

EDIT: Just played vector racer and it's actually a lot simpler than I expected. I thought you were making a full blown 2d racing game. What I've told you is still very applicable, but you'll need to make a few adjustments, particularly to the way you handle rotation. You'll definitely want to look up the [racing line](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LxMSdvnm0Ms). I don't have the time at the moment to go over the mathematics of the racing line, but [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/289575/car-racing-how-to-calculate-the-radius-of-the-racing-line-through-a-turn-of-var) should help you calculate it.

EDIT2: Updated Velocity section. I'll do some calculations to figure out a faster heuristic, but what is present is enough to check 3-10 moves ahead without major performance issues.

Comment: If you had followed the link, you would have seen that floating point co-ords don't make any sense for this game.

Comment: @j_random_hacker Yeah, I just did that and made an edit. Thanks for the heads up. Nonetheless, much of what I've said still is quite applicable. I think the hardest part may be deciding which rotation angles will fit to the grid.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, I will try your suggestions and get back to you. I only have 1 question: why do I still need rotation angles in my implementation? Turning a "car" in Vector Racer depends in the next available positions, which in turn they depend on the previous position i.e. the velocity used

Comment: @fatherjim91 I made an update to velocity now that I have a spare moment. I'll see if I can figure out a formula for taking good turns.